# Information about the Nantong dialect

Tags: topolect, resources

I want to learn the dialect spoken in Nantong. Are there any resources to help me?

Comment: 南通话音系拼音详解  http://wenku.baidu.com/view/d4c01134f18583d048645918.html

Comment: I think this question **should not** be closed because the off-topic rule says "... We do maintain a list of generally-useful resources for learning **Mandarin** ..." but this question is not about Mandarin.

Comment: I agree with @Stan.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some documents about Nantong dialect, but it's still difficult for Chinese in other areas.

http://wapwenku.baidu.com/view/09e3c92aaaea998fcc220e42.html?ssid=0&from=1099b&uid=0&pu=usm@3,sz@1320_2001,ta@iphone_1_9.2_3_601&bd_page_type=1&baiduid=2B26F0FC87EAF856CC6D8FCB7EA56F60&tj=wenku_3_0_10_title#2